# Can we use webservices to copy files from one location to another in C#

Tags: c#, copy

I want to copy files from one location(say pittsburgh) to another location(say melbourne) using the network share. The normal file copy takes more time for copying the files(usually in GB)
Can I use webservices to improve the performance or is there any other alternative?

Thanks

Comment: If a network share isn't fast enough (regardless of size), you might be better off copying it to a flash drive (or drives) and FedExing it.

Comment: @Joel: thanks for the wise suggestion. I was just wondering if there is any alternative in doing this, which i am not aware of. anyways thanks for your time

Comment: @superstar - not without delving into some of the more complicated methods of data transfer as mentioned by @Steven Sudit. Direct network share is typically the fastest because it deals with the fewest layers between the data and the actual transport. And if you do employ some of the crazier methods to compress, break up and transport data, you'll still probably find those methods faster over a network share than ftp or http because of the additional software layers.

Comment: This is not a case where you would want to use a web service. I would suggest attempting to compress your files before transferring them. [FreeArc](http://www.freearc.org/) is fast, has excellent compression ratios, and free.

Comment: @Joel: A direct network share translates to named pipes over TCP/IP. You could probably speed things up by going to TCP/IP directly, particularly as it might simplify security.

Comment: @Chris: Compression is not a bad idea, if the data can be compressed. This can be used alongside other solutions.

Comment: @Steven Sudit - If you have the capability/wherewithall to start programming sockets, but you're really only adding your own application layer to the mix. If it's not done properly, you could add more latency than the named pipes. The question would be what would be the realized speed benefit since the named pipe would only be looked up once per file.

Comment: @Joel: In my experience, yes, it would make a significant speed difference. I'm not particularly afraid of sockets, and there's not much here that's complicated. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, don't: just follow HTTP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webservices might work, but it would be better to use a protocol designed for transferring files across the Internet, such as FTP.

There is a bunch of FTP [libraries](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/FtpClient.aspx) and [tutorials](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/05/10/ftpdotnet.htm) out there.

Webservices do not have any special properties that will speedup connections and file transfers. Lag time and throughput will still be the same.

Comment: even FTP takes longer time for the file transfer, usually in GB's

Comment: Maybe your network is just saturated. Have you profiled it while transfering a file?

Comment: "longer" is a relative term, longer than what?

Comment: @superstar - GBs will always take a large amount of times, in particular across continents...

Comment: @Oded: that is true. Thats the reason i asked for an alternative to improve the performance (if any)

Comment: @superstar - There is no magic. Compression may help. And of course, never underestimate the bandwidth of a truck full of blue ray disks ;)

Comment: Oded, there's no magic, but there are definitely ways to improve upon FTP.

Comment: @Oded: okay, so webservices is out of question here(not a big change in performance) right?

Comment: @Steven Sudit - I am sure, but in the context of the question, webservices are a non starter.

Comment: @superstar - pretty much. Perhaps overnighting a burned DVD with a currier would be more cost effective.

Comment: @Oded: I think we're all in agreement regarding web services. As for the overnight courier, it has great bandwidth but poor latency. :-)

Answer (score 1):

FTP should still be king of file transfers, transfering files is what it was designed to do.   I dont think you can get much better than that across the internet.

Comment: Sure you can. I linked to one example in my answer, and described another. FTP is nothing great.

Comment: FTP clients can use multiple connections as well, making that point kinda moot.

Comment: By "multiple", are we talking about "two"?

Comment: No, by multiple I mean "more than 1", a smart client will add more connections until it hits a point of diminishing returns.

Comment: The FTP I'm familiar with has a control connection and a data connection. Would you please post the link to the RFC that defines an extension allowing multiple data connections?

Comment: @Steven Sudit: You dont need an RFC extension to have multiple connections, how do you think a client like FileZilla can connect to multiple servers at once?  Does it use other ports? No.  How do you think an FTP server can serve to multiple clients at once?  Take two seconds to think how file-resume works.  If a client requests a file using file resume multiple times, it can download the file in several synchronous peices, similar to how bit torrent works.

Comment: Yes, of course a client can connect to multiple servers, but that's not what we're talking about. We're talking about sending a single file over multiple sockets at the same time. This is important because the overlapping overcomes latency. To the best of my knowledge, FTP does not support this. If I'm wrong, I want to learn, so please throw an RFC at me or some other reliable source.

Answer (score 1):

Web services are not particularly helpful here. While there are dedicated products that perform efficient, long-distance transfers of large files (see http://www.asperasoft.com/en/technology_sections), the basic trick is to overcome latency by sending chunks in parallel. This can be done over HTTP just fine.

Comment: Considering this is a correct answer, I find it odd that it's been downvoted, particularly without explanation. I guess someone here is being "strategic" because they've confused SO with a video game.

Comment: Damn you for upvoting me! :-)